# Order of router precedence in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to understand the order precedence in express.js. For example, as bellow code

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var api = require('./routes/api');


app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/users', users);

app.use('/:name', function(req, res, next) {    
    console.log('from app.js name:', req.params.name);   

    res.render('index', {
        title: req.params.name
    });
}, routes);

app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {   
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'MainPage'
    });
});
```

If a request come from client localhost:3000/api/abc and localhost:3000/user/abc, the response from api and user module. But if I make a request like localhost:3000/myName/xyz, the app module return a response. This behavior let me concern about what is precedence of expressjs and what is correct order for router modules. Why routers do not confuse between actions "api", "users" and parameter ":name". Please let me understand clearly how express does and what is precedence.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The order is first come first serve.

In your case, if user hits /api, he will get response from api, but if you write `/:name` route before `/api`, `/:name` will serve for `/api` requests also.

> **Case1: `/api` will serve requests for `/api`.**

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var api = require('./routes/api');


app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/users', users);

app.use('/:name', function(req, res, next) {    
    console.log('from app.js name:', req.params.name);   

    res.render('index', {
        title: req.params.name
    });
}, routes);

app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {   
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'MainPage'
    });
});
```

> **Case2: `/:name` serves requests for `/api` and `/users`**

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var api = require('./routes/api');

app.use('/:name', function(req, res, next) {    
    console.log('from app.js name:', req.params.name);   

    res.render('index', {
        title: req.params.name
    });
}, routes);

app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/users', users);



app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {   
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'MainPage'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank too much @Laxmikant Dange but if I do nothing in api module or users modules, why the app.use("/", func(){}) acts as server...?. It responses the MainPage..??

Comment: Where in the ExpressJS documentation, can I find information about precedence rules of use() and get() routes.

Comment: @hoan because there is no `:name` so it doesn't match `/:name`

Answer (score 5):

The example given in the [ExpressJS documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html) is pretty simple and was unfortunately difficult to find. I only found it through [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317119/nodejs-express-app-use-sequence-and-usage).

> Middleware functions are executed sequentially, therefore the order of middleware inclusion is important

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('This is the only thing that ever happens')
}
app.use(...) // never used
app.get(...) // never used
app.put(...) // never used
app.post(...) // never used
```