# Expressjs routing precedence again

Tags: node.js, express

As my question in [Order of router precedence in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603818/order-of-router-precedence-in-express-js/32604002#32604002). I know that the order of express.js is first come first serve. But as code bellows, I don't understand that why the '__dirname' has declared and fixed in above of other code but whaterver I call javascript from ./public/abc.js, the app return a HTML markup of mainpage.
My pages include some javascript and it cannot be loaded. The server return 100% HTML

I am using express generator and folders is structured follows.

NodeJS

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/users', users);

app.use('/:shopName', function(req, res, next) {
    req.shopName = req.params.shopName;
    next();
}, routes);

app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'MainPage'
    });
});
```

Client Javascript put in script tags like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='./public/javascripts/Crypto/crytoUtils.js'></script>
```

The browser send out error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <   cryptoUtils.js " in console and when I click in a link, I see the mainpage HTML markup..

Help me solve the problem ... pls. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the js file should be **./abc.js**, **public** is left out unless you set that as the root for static files using:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

To be clear, I suggest **NOT** using the above code, and instead modify your url in the script tag src attribute to appropriately target the file at it's location of **/javascripts/Crypto/crytoUtils.js**

Comment: Then the path you are using is still incorrect. This is a very simple problem, you simply need to use the correct path, the same path that you would use to get to that file in your browser. This isn't a code issue or a programming problem. Just the wrong url.