# Why some HTTP methods such as PUT and POST are not supported on certain path?

Tags: node.js, http, express, server

Why will this code respond to the request while the below one is not supported?

---------------------------These are supported-------------------------

```
app.put('/dishes/:dishId', (req, res, next) => {
  res.write('Updating the dish: ' + req.params.dishId + '\n');
  res.end('Will update the dish: ' + req.body.name + 
        ' with details: ' + req.body.description);
});


app.post('/dishes', (req, res, next) => {
 res.end('Will add the dish: ' + req.body.name + ' with details: ' + req.body.description);
});
```

---------------------------These are not supported------------------------

```
 app.put('/dishes', (req, res, next) => {
  res.statusCode = 403;
  res.end('PUT operation not supported on /dishes');
});

 app.post('/dishes/:dishId', (req, res, next) => {
  res.statusCode = 403;
  res.end('POST operation not supported on /dishes/'+ req.params.dishId);
});
```

Comment: the below just dosent feel right it does not define the operation properly and you will always put/post for a particular dish and not for dishes.

Comment: What do you mean by "not supported"?  Also, I know that you are using different methods (PUT, POST, etc), but be mindful that route definitions are order dependent.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32603818/691711.