# NodeJS App.Get Order Error

Tags: node.js

I have got strange error in nodejs.

My application works perfectly when the order is

```
app.get('/api/:pid', productController.getColor);

app.get('/', homeController.index);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory/:category_product/:product', productController.index);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory/:category_product', categoryController.products);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory', categoryController.subcategory);
app.get('/:category', categoryController.index);
```

But when i change the order to

```
app.get('/', homeController.index);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory/:category_product/:product', productController.index);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory/:category_product', categoryController.products);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory', categoryController.subcategory);
app.get('/:category', categoryController.index);

app.get('/api/:pid', productController.getColor);
```

My website crashes. Error is so irrelevant. I dont know why does it happen

I guess the problem occurs when nodejs checking all urls and /api/65625499 (i made up the id) fits with '/:category/:subcategory' so it goes crash.

I cant make '/:category/:subcategory' static because i dont know what category would be choosen etc.

How can i solve this situation? Thanks

## ERROR

```
/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:132
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined
    at /home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/controllers/categoryController.js:28:40
    at /home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3930:16
    at cb (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1314:14)
    at result (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:413:17)
    at executeCallback (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:405:9)
    at handleCallback (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
    at self.close (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:934:60)
    at handleCallback (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
    at completeClose (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:1073:14)
    at Cursor.close (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:1086:10)
    at /home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:934:21
    at handleCallback (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:178:5)
    at setCursorNotified (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:555:3)
    at /home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:664:16
    at queryCallback (/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:242:16)
    at /home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:541:18
```

In a nutshell, error is in codes of subcategory

Comment: Is there a way to make the url's along the lines of `/categories/:category/...` ? I'm very sure having parameters as as the first match after '/' could be disastrous in terms of matching. I feel like restful principles aren't being applied

Comment: If i cant find any solution, i would do it but i dont want to add extra urls in it. Thanks by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## About reading errors

From the error code, all I see the error is in code from this file, which is not shared here.

```
/home/berkin/Projects/OSF_Academy/controllers/categoryController.js:28:40
```

I'd suggest checking that file since it's saying it cannot find something within that line.

Now, back to your routes. The error is relevant, because of two reasons,

## Ordering of Routes

The ordering of routes is very important. It's always first come, first serve.

If you have `/api/:something` first and then `/:category`, it will match `/api` first.

Rather than me explaining this again, you can go ahead and read the following in depth [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604002/6161265).

## No Error Catching

If there is an error in your route, you should catch it, display it and move to next route. This following is from the actual expressjs docs. On a route, there is `request`, `resource` and a `next` callback.

[image]

So I'd create an error handler and catch it, then proceed to `next()`. The [expressJS doc](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use) is full of `next()` callback examples.

#### Final words

You should be able to structure them the following way which will match the home router first, and then api, finally if anything is left, it will try to match the categories.

```
app.get('/', homeController.index);
app.get('/api/:pid', productController.getColor); // <-- Put API first
app.get('/:category/:subcategory/:category_product/:product', productController.index);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory/:category_product', categoryController.products);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory', categoryController.subcategory);
app.get('/:category', categoryController.index);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah i understand you very well. Thanks alot. I'll use next tomorrow now i have to sleep :D

Comment: Also file needs some variables for example mens/mens-clothes etc. and insted of mens and mens-clothes, api and pid comes in then error occurs.