# When fixing react-routing for production, fetch cannot find api url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, fetch

I have a react front-end with an express back end. The express just serves the static build files from the react side in production. I was having a problem with React routing working in production, as many have had, so I fixed it as so:

server.js:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/api/customers', (req, res) => {
  const customers = [
    {id: 2, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Case'},
    {id: 3, firstName: 'Foo', lastName: 'Bar'},
  ];

  res.json(customers);
});
```

The '/*' solve the routing problem in production, but now the fetch for the '/api/customers' does not work anymore.

customer.js:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/customers')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(customers => this.setState({customers}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', customers)))
      .catch(() => console.log('Error'));
  }
```

This fetch request logs 'Error' when ran. It seems as though the url for the api is changing somehow as a result of the '/*' change in server.js, but I am not sure how I should change the fetch argument to make it work. The fetch was working using just the '/':

server.js:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

However, this obviously stops react routing from working in production. What do I need to change my fetch argument to in order to make this work?

Comment: what has this with react-router I dont get it?

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of the routes in `server.js`:

```
app.get('/api/customers', () => {});
app.get('/*', () => {});
```

The routes in express are [first come first served](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604002/2957110), and as "/api/customers" matches "/*", it will return your index.html if your list them the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for this solutiion @David Filipidisz !! The order DOES affect the routes. this is my working code

server.js

...ipmorts here ...

````
app.use('/users', require('./users/users.controller'));
app.use('/machineLearning', require('./machineLearning/machineLearning.controller'));
app.use('/public', require('./public/public.controller'));

//for Prod
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../L10-ui/dist')));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../L10-ui/dist', 'index.html'));
});```
````