# Express Routes for ejected create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, express, static, routes, router

I want to serve another static page for the route "/about",
now I have :

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
    console.log("here")
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'about.html'));
});
```

and I also have a post request

```
app.post('/getfrontpage', (req, res) => {
    console.log("FIRST PAGE", req.body.params.page)
});
```

The post request works, I use axios to make a call, but the "/about" route doesn't work when I'm changing the url

Comment: Hi,

Hard to tell. I see you have a react front end. Your react front end routes have to be exactly the same as express api's if not using hash routes.

Another option may be to have an array of your api functions passed to app.use on '/' and use next() to call next function in the stack.

- The truth is out there

Comment: You can also try to have another app.use on '/about' route to serve about static file specifally then  use next() to call the callback to send file. Hope this helps.



 - The truth is out there

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any errors on the server side?

The example above works for me: https://runkit.com/dionnis/5ab936152f32d7001211d85f

Note: I changed `app.post('/getfrontpage'` to `app.get('/getfrontpage'`

Comment: I don't have any errs, but I can't see the console.log("here"), and I still see the index.html instead of about.html, I think that the problem with a webpack, created by "create react app"

Comment: Webpack for "create react app" and the express app is completely different things.
Can you just test express app first by manually creating "about.html" file and opening it?

Comment: I have about.html file, but every time I'm trying to get "/about" I still see the index.html content

Comment: Try to change the order of `app.get('/',` and `app.get('/about'`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603818/order-of-router-precedence-in-express-js

BTW: don't forget after any changes restart the server.

Comment: Changing the order doesn't work, but it works if I completely remove app.get('/')

Comment: I think I have a problem because of this line : app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));  but without it the app doesnt work at all

Comment: Actually, you are right. Having static middleware - you don't need to specify `about.html` page at all, it should work without `app.get('/about', `