# Deploy express and react with route prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to serve a react app (that use router) using express. The react app supposedly is accessible through `/dashboard`.

Everything is working well on the `/dashboard` route that supposed to show the login page. But if I try to access different routes, example `/dashboard/foo` It shows nothing.
It turns out when the HTML page request the `.js` file, the server return with the `index.html` file instead of the `.js` file.

I'm using this code in the `index.js` file:

```
app.use(
  ['/dashboard', '/dashboard/*'], 
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dashboard')),
);
```

have also tried this code:

```
app.use(
  '/dashboard',
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dashboard')),
);
app.get(
  '/dashboard/*',
  (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/dashboard/index.html"));
  }
);
```

Comment: You could just redirect all routes to index.html from express side and let react router do its magic and taking care of all routes including `/dashboard` and `/dashboard/foo`

Comment: @tarzenchugh the thing that it's actually just `/` and `/foo` in react-router. And the express also used to serve another route such as `/api/bar`

Answer (score 0):

He, routers define order is make sense,
Here is go example [Order of router precedence in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603818/order-of-router-precedence-in-express-js) 
and documentation https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

when you try to access /dashboard/something, because of /dashboard 1st in order, you ever access /dashboard and not /dashboard/somethink, all about order here

Comment: This doesn't work and it seems like even if I don't change the order, `/dashboard/something` should always go to `/dashboard/something` even if it meets `/dashboard` first