# Why do I get a 403 error when calling one route, but not another?

Tags: javascript, express, rest, controller

I have a "/" route on my "events" router and the controller for that route just sends all event documents.  I tried implementing another route so I can send only future events.  The route is very similar to the base "/" but every time I try to call it I get a 403.  I would even change it so that it's literally the same functionality as the "/" route or very similar and I would still get 403.  I don't understand why the base route works but not this one.  I tested it with a post instead of get it worked that time, but I don't understand why, because of how similar the controllers are.

```
export const getEvents = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const events = await Event.find();
        res.status(200).json(events);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};



export const getFuture = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let now = moment().toISOString();
        const events = await Event.find({date: { $gte: now}});
        res.status(200).json(events);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};
```

And here are the routes

```
router.get("/", getEvents);

router.get("/future", getFuture);
```

controllers are properly imported

Comment: The problem probably isn't with the controllers. Can you also post your routes for us to look at?

Comment: @NetByMatt added my routes

Comment: This looks like an order-of-routes problem. "/" is typically last. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310355/does-the-order-of-routes-matter-in-express