# How to get to a route if theres a route/params in the same level

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

so I tried to get to `stud_router.post(/students/add )` ,but I get directed to `stud_router.get(/students/:email )` instead, I want to go `/students/add` but it sends me to `/students/:email` instead of `/students/add`.

```js
stud_router.post(`/students/add` , (req,res,next) => {
    res.render(`studentadd/students_add`)  
})
```

```js
stud_router.get(`/students/:email` , (req,res ,next) => {
        const found = data.some( stud => stud.email === req.params.email)
        if (found) {
            res.send(data.filter( stud => stud.email === req.params.email ))
        } else {
            res.status(400).send({ msg: `no member with the email of ${req.params.email}`})
        }

})
```

Comment: Define `/students/add` **first**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of router precedence in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603818/order-of-router-precedence-in-express-js)

Comment: i've already tried it, but the order didn't work.

Comment: It would help greatly if you include some actual code in your question. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: One thing that does not make sense here is that a `.get()` and a `.post()` do not conflict as they never match the same request so order between them is not relevant.  If `stud_router.get(/students/:email )` is matching, then the request MUST be a GET request, not a POST so perhaps you also have a problem with the type of request.

Comment: oohhh i see, i think my understanding of get and post is wrong, thank you @jfriend00 i found my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem in your question.  These two routes:

```
stud_router.post(`/students/add`, ...)
stud_router.get(`/students/:email` , ...)
```

Do not overlap in any way because one is for a GET request and one is for a POST request.  An incoming request will only match one of these requests.  So, if something is going to `stud_router.get('/students/:email' , ...)`, then it must be GET and it would never match the other route.

So, it appears that perhaps the client is confused about whether it's sending a POST or a GET.  Or, your route definitions are confused about what they intend to match.