# Express Router() method - only /api route is working while others are not

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I am getting a generic error "An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1." When I try to connect to anything other than `/api` (`/api/genres` for example). My code looks like this:

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

require("./startup/cors")(app);
require("./startup/routes")(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

**/startup/routes.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const genres = require("../routes/genres");
const home = require("../routes/home");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(express.json());

  app.use("/api", home);
  app.use("/api/genres", genres);
};
```

**/routes/home.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (request, response) => {
  return response.send("API HOME");
});

module.exports = router;
```

**/routes/genres.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (request, response) => {
  return response.status(200).send("success!");
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:80/api/genres, it loads forever.

I have created an entirely new project with only the four files mentioned (plus `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`, and `package.json`), but I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs due to Express' router precedence order. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604002/10473393) for more info about this.

> TL;DR: First route is the one that is evaluated by Express.

So your code makes express go into `app.use("/api", home);`, as it contains `/api` and takes precedence.

One way to solve this is to use `app.use` pointing to genres' path, i.e.:

```js
// /routes/home.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const genresRouter = require("./genres")

router.use("/genres", genresRouter)

router.get("/", (request, response) => {
  return response.send("API HOME");
});

module.exports = router;
```

This will make all routes from `genresRouter` accessible by `/api/genres/*`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** - In my actual project inside `/routes/home.js`, I was trying to handle unknown endpoints by having a `/api/:endpoint` route.

The router couldn't tell whether to handle unknown endpoints using `/api/:endpoint` in `/routes/home.js` or `app.use("/api/genres", genres)` in `index.js`. Poor design was the source of my error (NOT any syntax errors).

Thank you for taking time out of your day to help me troubleshoot my issue!