Unable to receive api response using express js
Controller for cart
const Cart = require("../models/Cart");

const getCart = (req, res)=> {
    Cart.find()
    .then((cart) => {
        res.status(200).json("hello")
        // return "hello"
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.json(err)
    })
}

const addCart = (req, res) => {
    // const cart = new Cart({
    //     item_id: req.body.item_id,
    //     quantity: req.body.quantity,
    //     amount: req.body.amount
    // })

    const cart = new Cart({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        price: req.body.price,
        quantity: req.body.quantity
    })

    cart.save()
    .then(() => {
        res.json('added to cart')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.json(err)
    })
}

module.exports = {
    getCart,
    addCart
}

Controller for Item
const Item = require("../models/Item");


const getItem = (req, res) => {
    Item.find()
    .then((item) => {
        res.json(item)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // console.log(err)
        res.json(err)

    })
    // res.send("I'm item route")
}

const getOneItem = (req, res) => {
    // Item.findOne({_id: '6626a3c852da8b83396606aa'})
    // .then((item) => {
    //     res.json(item)
    // })
    // .catch((err) => {
    //     res.json(err)

    // })
    const id = req.params.id;
    res.json(id)
}

const createItem =(req, res) => {
    const item = new Item({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
        price: req.body.price
    });

    item.save()
    .then((item)=>{
        console.log('item saved')
        res.json(item)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.json(err)
    })

}

const deleteItem = (req, res) => {
    Item.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('item deleted')

    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}

const editItem = (req, res) => {
    Item.findOneAndUpdate({_id: '6626a3c852da8b83396606aa'},{
        $set: {
            title: req.body.title,
            description: req.body.description,
            quantity: req.body.quantity,
            price: req.body.price
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('item updated')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}

// const getItem = (req, res) => {

// }

module.exports = {
    getItem,
    createItem,
    deleteItem,
    editItem,
    getOneItem
}

Router
const router = require("express").Router();
const { getItem, createItem, deleteItem, editItem, getOneItem } = require("./controllers/Item")
const { addCart, getCart } = require('./controllers/cart')

router.get("/", getItem);
router.get("/:id", getOneItem);

router.post("/item", createItem)

router.delete('/:id', deleteItem)

router.put('/edit', editItem)

router.get("/cart", getCart)
router.post('/cart', addCart)


module.exports = router;

The problem is when I try to use the api "http://localhost:3001/cart" I only receive response "cart" while I'm expecting list of data.
The api "http://localhost:3001/" is working fine I'm receiving list of data.
I have tried to used the getItem controller in get request "/cart" and It returned list of data I guess I'm having issue on my getCart controller?

what response you are getting from this http://localhost:3001/cart?

Your router.get("/cart", getCart) needs to be placed above router.get("/:id", getOneItem);. Alternatively you could use a semantically appropriate route such as router.get("/items/:id", getOneItem); so that you wouldn't get path mismatches.

Does this answer your question? Order of router precedence in express.js

GET /cart is triggering your /:id route, not /cart since the /:id route was defined first.

I’m expecting to receive “hello” response from Get /cart since i have connected the getCart controller in. Thank you for your suggestion but ain’t make sense kindly explain more?

The definition order of routes is important in Express. Since /:id means “url with a slash and a word” it matches /:id since it is defined before /cart. You can read more about it in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603818/order-of-router-precedence-in-express-js
