route with query string not working in express
I am not being able to retrieve the query strings that I sent through a specific route on a node server using req.query (url?var=value)
It seems that it never enters the route
if I modify the routes to use req.params it works
I would like to know what I am doing wrong
I am testing the endpoint from the browser but I can't get it to work, I only see an empty array in the developer console.
To reduce the complexity I have put only one console.log inside the route controller to verify if by entering the url + query string,  returns it, unfortunately it does not
First route (router.get("/:id", bienesPorOficina);) works just fine
Second route /router.get("/nombre/:cod", obtenerBien);) has been modified in order to use req.params, so i have to got to localhost:3000/bienes/nombre/xx where x is a number.
3rd route (router.get("/nom", obtenerBien2);) is a simplification of the second route where I tried to check if I can access that route using query strings. localhost:3000/bienes/nom?cod=123 just returns an empty array in develper console and not showing the console.log in obtenerBien2 function
relevant code
server.js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const bienesRouter = require("./routes/bienesRouter.js");
const oficinasRouter = require("./routes/oficinasRouter.js");
const { checkConnection } = require("./models/db");
const { log } = require("console");

const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.json()); // Middleware para analizar cuerpos de solicitudes JSON

app.use("/bienes", bienesRouter);
app.use("/ubicaciones", oficinasRouter);

// app.use("/oficinas", oficinasRouter)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor iniciado en el puerto ${port}`);
  checkConnection();
});


routes/bienesRouter.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../models/db");
const {
  bienesPorOficina,
  obtenerBien,
  obtenerBien2,
} = require("../controllers/bienesController");

// router.get("/", obtenerBienes);
router.get("/:id", bienesPorOficina);
router.get("/nombre/:cod", obtenerBien);
router.get("/nom", obtenerBien2);

module.exports = router;


controllers/bienesControllers.js
const db = require("../models/db");

const bienesPorOficina = async (req, res) => {
  const oficina_id = req.params.id;

  if (!oficina_id) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Oficina ID no proporcionado" });
  }
  try {
    const [rows] = await db.pool.execute(
      "SELECT b.id, b.descripcion, b.cod_MINCYT from bienes b INNER JOIN oficinas o on b.oficinas_id = o.id WHERE o.id = ?",
      [oficina_id]
    );
    res.json(rows);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};

const obtenerBien = async (req, res) => {
  const codigoBien = req.params.cod;
  console.log("Código de bien:", codigoBien);
  if (!codigoBien) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Código de bien no proporcionado" });
  }

  try {
    const [rows] = await db.pool.execute(
      "SELECT descripcion FROM bienes WHERE cod_MINCYT = ?",
      [codigoBien]
    );
    res.json(rows);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};

const obtenerBien2 = (req, res) => {
  const codigo = req.query.cod;
  console.log(codigo);
};

module.exports = { bienesPorOficina, obtenerBien, obtenerBien2 };



Hi, The following post may help - Order of router precedence in express.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603818/order-of-router-precedence-in-express-js

This was extremely helpful
`app.use("/api", apiRouter);
router.get("/:id, function1);
router.get("/secondaryRoute, function2);
`
This way all requests will be handled by function1, regardless they hit localhost:3000/api or localhost:3000/api/secondaryRoute
router.get("/:id") is what causes the issue

Thanks for the confirmation. If you have not done, request you may kindly extend your valuable vote for the post referenced here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603818/order-of-router-precedence-in-express-js, the very same you have already used. The very little time and the very little tick of yours will help to make good and useful contents in the Internet more acceptable and encouraging to many others as well.
