# How to use exact match in ExpressJs router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, router

I have two routes as follow in my ExpressJs application

```
router.get("/task/", Controller.retrieveAll);
router.get("/task/seed/", Controller.seed);
```

If I make a request on `/task/seed/` instead of `Controller.seed`, `Controller.retrieveAll` is getting called.

So basically router matches the `/task/` string before it checks the proceeding string, in my case `/seed`.

How can I make sure that the router does check the full string (kind of exact match)?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of router precedence in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603818/order-of-router-precedence-in-express-js)

Comment: @AsadJivani yes it does. Actually, I raised this question because I was hoping to see some alternative to the order of paths but it seems like there's none.

Answer (score 4):

The example you show using `router.get()` or `app.get()` does not actually occur.  `router.get()` does not do partial matches unless you're using wildcards or regexes.

I verified that in this simple test app:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get("/task/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("got /task");
});

app.get("/task/seed", (req, res) => {
    res.send("got /task/seed");
});

app.listen(80);
```

When you request `/task/seed`, you get the message `got /task/seed` so, it does route correctly.

---

On the other hand, `router.use()` does do partial matches so this problem could occur if your actual code was using `.use()`, not `.get()`.  In that case, you just need to either switch to the verb-specific `.get()` instead of using the generic `.use()` or you need to order your routes from the most specific to the least-specific so that the most-specific declaration gets a chance to match first:

```
router.use("/task/seed/", Controller.seed);
router.use("/task/", Controller.retrieveAll);
```

---

In case you're curious, the two main differences between `router.use()` and `router.get()` are:

1. `.get()` only matches GET requests while `.use()` matches all HTTP verbs.
2. `.get()` only does full path matches while `.use()` will match any URL path that starts with what you specify.

Answer (score 3):

Execution of express router middleware functions is sequential. There is no keyword like `exact`, as we have in `react-router` to make the router check for exact path match.

To make your code work, and always when creating express routes, have the path with the higher specificity above the path with lesser specificity.

So, this should work:

```js
router.get("/task/seed/", Controller.seed);
router.get("/task/", Controller.retrieveAll);
```

These earlier StackOverflow answers will be very helpful:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604002/6772055
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27317835/6772055

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to get to know about some alternatives other than the order of routes. But since your answer solves the problem I will upvote it for sure.

Comment: This is not correct.  `router.get()` does not do partial matches.  `router.use()` does, but that is not what the OP shows in their question.