# Node.js asynchronous order of execution

Tags: node.js

The node.js code I produced works fine, I just wanted to understand why `app.use(passwordProtected)` doesn't run when accessing the `'/'` endpoint, only runs for `'/advanced-view'`.

I would have thought because they are multiple asynchronous operations, the `passwordProtected` function would run for `'/'` as well:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) { .... }

app.use(passwordProtected)

app.get('/advanced-view', function(req, res) { ... }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you considered moving the `app.use(…)` invocation to *above* your `/` route definition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS/Express app.use sequence and usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317119/nodejs-express-app-use-sequence-and-usage)

Comment: Middlewares are run in the top-to-bottom order. Move `app.use(passwordProtected)` at the top and you will get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks @Yousaf, I understand it now. The code works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

1. The app.use() function is used to mount the specified middleware function (are the functions that have access to the request object and response object, or we can call it a response-request cycle) at the path which is being specified. The middleware function is executed when the base of the requested path matches the path.
2. app.get(): This function tells the server what to do when get requests at a given route.